# Add http or https for user input validation

Tags: php

```
$xml = $_GET['url']

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

..
..
```

if the user put without http or https my script will be broken, is concatenation a good way to validation in this case?

Comment: Check for it with regex or substr?

Comment: Possibly depends on the use case

Comment: `preg_match(/^http(s)?:\/\/, $xml)` should check your url for the correct beginning of an url. When not available concat it: `'http://'.$xml`

Comment: What happens if the user provides a string that will never be a valid url even _with_ http/https?

Comment: @Mouser what if the user's site is https?

Comment: You can never know. You could use a try catch on the load, if fails, then return incorrect url to the user.

Comment: @wolfemm then use this regex `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/` And there are even more complex one for even beter validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: no, if the user just put www.abc.com, how can regex know their site is http or https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is checking for the presence of `http://` or `https://` at the beginning of the string.

```
if (preg_match('/^http(s)?:\/\//', $xml, $matches) === 1) {
    if ($matches[1] === 's') {
        // it's https
    } else {
        // it's http
    }
} else {
    // there is neither http nor https at the beginning
}
```

Comment: How can I know the users' site is https or http? regrex is not enough right?

Comment: If they don't include it, there is no way of really knowing, but you could make an assumption or generate an error.

Comment: Then the regex is no point. My plan : use parse_url to check whether is http or https, then only use the regex? right?

Comment: The new regex and code will check if it's https or http or nothing.

Comment: no, if the user just put www.abc.com, how can regex know their site is http or https?

Comment: Dear @JamieEason, It can not! There is no way of knowing this. You can only ask the user to repost his url with the correct scheme eg. http

Answer (score -1):

You are using a `get` method. Or this is done by AJAX, or the user appends a url in the `querystring` You are not posting a form?

Concatenation isn't going to cut it, when the url is faulty. You need to check for this.

You can put an input with placeholder on the page, to "force" the user to use `http://`. This should be the way to go in HTML5.

```
 <input type="text" pattern="^(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$" placeholder="http://" title="URLs need to be proceeded by http:// or https://" >
```

This should check and forgive some errors. If an url isn't up to spec this will return an error, as it should. The user should revise his url.

```
$xml = $_GET['url']

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
if (!preg_match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/, $xml ) )
{
    echo 'This url is not valid.';
    exit;
}
else if (!preg_match(/^http(s)?:\/\/, $xml))
{
    //no http present
    $orgUrl = $xml;
    $xml = "http://".$orgUrl; 
    //extended to cope with https://
    $loaded = loadXML();
    if (substr($loaded, 0, 5) == "false")
    {
        //this attempt failed.
        $xml = "https://".$orgUrl;
        $loaded = loadXML();
        if (substr($loaded, 0, 5) == "false")
        {
             echo substr($loaded, 6);
             exit;
        }

    }
}
else
{  
    $loaded = loadXML();
}

function loadXML()
{
  try {
     return $xmlDoc->load($xml);
  }
  catch($Ex)
  {
     return echo 'false Your url could\'t be retrieved. Are you sure you\'ve entered it correctly?';
  }
}
```

You can also use `curl` to check the url before loading xml:

```
$ch = curl_init($xml);

// Send request
curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "$error_message :: while loading url";
}

// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);
```

**Important side-note**: Using this methods to check if the url is available and than take the appropriate action can take a very long time, since the server response can take a while to return.

Comment: @JamieEason see my updated answer. This is about all you can do when you're depend on users posting urls.

Comment: ok, what if user's site is https://example.com but they type example.com? ur code give them http://example.com?

Comment: @jamieeason then my code will validate example.com as valid url, puts `http://` in front of it and tries to load the xml

Comment: @jamieeason I can't think of any more to handle validation on server. This code should prevent the most common input errors. However it's is still better to check the validness of the url on the client side and force the user to supply the url in the format you need it, then you can do a simple url check on the server.